# how to get product group price by customer group id, without logged in

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, customer-group, group-price

I need to replace the product price with group price for the product which is in the cart.[without logged in any customers].

I am getting a product from the cart and getting a price and other information.
I am unable to get product customerGroupId and group price and all.

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $cartItems = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item)
        {
            //Mage::log(print_r($item->getCustomerGroupId(), true));
         //   Mage::log(print_r($item, true));
            $item->setCustomerGroupId(4);
            Mage::log(print_r($item->getPrice(), true));
 Mage::log(print_r($item->getGroupPrice(), true));
}
```

The above code not able to print group price or unable to set product customerGroup

Help me to get an answer for this,
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

Charlie.you can not get Customer group price  from item`.

Here `$item  Mage_Sales_Quote_Item object and it not product object Mage_Catalog_Product` .

So, you `can not get group price   from $item->getGroupPrice()` and but you can  only item price on here and using `$item->getPrice()` you `can get Product  cart price not group price`.

If`you need to load product Object (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')) by product id($item->getProduct()->getId())`